# Getting 'Proxy authentication error' in genymotion when trying to sign in to add virtual devices

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

I have installed genymotion application and wanted to add virtual devices from genymotion cloud when i try to sign in with my working credentials i always get the error saying 'proxy authentication error'. My machine is behind a proxy and i have configured those details properly in the setting screen of genymotion.

Genymotion --> Settings --> Network screen. Have updated all the fields for Proxy url,port,username and password.

My proxy details are all correct but i still face this issue.Please help me to get this issue resolved.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried using the tools mentioned here: https://www.genymotion.com/?ref=driverlayer.com#!/support?chapter=proxy-incompatible#faq

Comment: Thanks a lot .... it worked with cntlm :)